# Is it possible to programatically disable 'Button Shapes' in iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

As the title states, is it possible to disable it? Granted this may not be a user-friendly thing to do but it does mess with the design of some of my apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of no way to do this short of reimplementing the UIKit controls that you want to have ignore the setting.

Please, *please* consider changing your design rather than attempt to subvert system settings. Button Shapes is an Accessibility setting for a reason: some users rely on this sort of thing to use apps at all, not just to change the appearance of the system.

(Reimplementing UIKit controls would exacerbate this problem, too, since you're not only avoiding one Accessibility setting but would also have to reimplement many others, whereas the standard UIKit controls give you pretty good accessibility support "for free.")

Comment: hi sorry for asking here.. i cant understand your answer , in short it is possible to remove underline programatically ??

Comment: You're probably better off asking a new question - underlining has little to do with Button Shapes.

Comment: I also have one control that is unusable with button shapes - the underline needs to be removed somehow.