# Customize Button shape in ios 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, accessibility, ios7.1

Apple has added [Button shape](http://www.todaysiphone.com/2014/03/switch-button-shapes-ios-7-1/) feature in ios 7.1. But I need to make it disable for my app or change its default color, shape to match UI of my app. It is possible without using custom type button? Please help me.

Comment: are you find the solution

Comment: @Spynet still now, no. I will share if I get or mark that as accepted ans.

Answer (score 3):

Sub class the button and try which shape you want....

```
#import "YourButton.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation YourButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
    mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ge.png"] CGImage]; // ge is the black & white png image
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    self.layer.mask = mask;
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}

@end
```

For your reference sample is attached [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l93r9cadj3bm2h8/ButtonSample.zip)

Answer (score 2):

These features reflect on apples default button control(may be nav bar).
You don't need to worry about,these features are not app specific but for all apps.

If you want to ignore, don't use default button, instead go with custom.

P.S. After editing question by OP:

You can't achieve this without using custom implementation.

For More:[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313847/is-it-possible-to-programatically-disable-button-shapes-in-ios-7-1)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can make it custom type & use image according to the way you want to view that.

Comment: Thanks, Using custom image is a solution, but is there anyway to change default feel and look?

Comment: @DevojyotiAich well the only way is to take custom type :)
well if you like answer than you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

IF you use a `UINavigationBar` or `UIToolbar` as the of the button then you will get a slightly darker color of the bar's tint color.

Otherwise you can get an underline whats color matches the text color, so i think this should not bother you. Leave it as it is.