# UIBarButton title text not showing up on modal view controller when "Button Shapes" accessibility feature is turned on

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

When I try to modally present a view controller the bar buttons on either side of the title of navigation bar are not showing up. This happens only when the "Buttons Shapes" accessibility feature is turned on under iPhone settings menu. It just shows up a plain blank white space. But when I try to tap the button I could see the button's presence and the button shape drawn around it.

Could some help and point me in right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing to text color of the button?

Comment: @atulkhatri Tried. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you set `tintColor`, `barTintColor`, and `barStyle` of `UINavigationBar`'s appearance. For a dark background and light foreground it works like this.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

It's all advisable to look at `UIBarButtonItem`'s appearance, e.g. `titleTextAttributes`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373815/how-can-the-appearance-of-button-shapes-enabled-through-the-accessibility-settin).